# how to catch object key inside array

Tags: javascript

I'm using `Object.keys()` to fetch the object key while iterating the parent array as shown below. I was wondering if there are other ways to capture the object key if I know that there will be only one. `arrOfObjs[i][keyArr[0]]` gives me a headache.

```
var arrOfObjs = [
    {"key1":"val1"},
    {"key2":"val2"},
    {"key3":"val3"},    
]
for(var i in arrOfObjs){
    var keyArr = Object.keys(arrOfObjs[i]);
    console.log(keyArr[0], arrOfObjs[i][keyArr[0]]);
}
```

Comment: What is problem with `keyArr[0]`?

Comment: *"I'm using Object.keys() to fetch the object key while iterating the parent array as shown below."* That's not what you're doing, no. The keys you're getting have nothing to do with the loop or the array. They relate to one entry *in* the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preface: Don't use `for-in` to loop over arrays as in your example, at least not unless you're sure of what you're doing. More about looping arrays [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

> I was wondering if there are other ways to capture the object key if I know that there will be only one.

There's no shorter version of getting the only own enumerable property name from an object than `Object.keys(obj)[0]`. But you can do it earlier if the `[0]` is bothering you:

```
for(var i in arrOfObjs){ // See note above, don't use for-in here
    var keyArr = Object.keys(arrOfObjs[i])[0];
    // Note ------------------------------^^^
    console.log(keyArr, arrOfObjs[i][keyArr]);
}
```

You *could* do this:

```
for(var i in arrOfObjs){ // See note above, don't use for-in here
    for (var key in arrOfObjs[i]) {
        console.log(key, arrOfObjs[i][key]);
        break; // You've said you know there's only one, but...
    }
}
```

...but it doesn't buy you anything other than (I suppose) avoiding calling `Object.keys`, and in fact your `Object.keys` code filters out inherited properties, which may be useful (though it's not necessary in your example).

The objects in your example don't have any inherited properties (unless someone's done something insane with `Object.prototype`), but to be fully equal to your `Object.keys` example, we'd have to throw in another function call:

```
for(var i in arrOfObjs){ // See note above, don't use for-in here
    for (var key in arrOfObjs[i]) {
        if (arrOfObj[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(key, arrOfObjs[i][key]);
            break; // You've said you know there's only one, but...
        }
    }
}
```

And in fact, to be **completely** the same, we'd have to go further:

```
for(var i in arrOfObjs){ // See note above, don't use for-in here
    for (var key in arrOfObjs[i]) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(arrOfObj[i], key)) {
            console.log(key, arrOfObjs[i][key]);
            break; // You've said you know there's only one, but...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought not looping the object would have been a boon. I will never use a for-in loop on an array again.

Comment: @WouldBeNerd: :-) Well, it has its purposes (sparse arrays), more in the link.

Comment: Thanks for all the info!

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't mind the `[0]`, I would first remove the for loop.
like:

> var arrOfKeys = arrOfObjs.map((obj) => Object.keys(obj)[0])

Answer (score -1):

you can do that with a very clean way by using **Underscore.js**

```
var keys = _.map(arrOfObjs, function(v, k) { return k; });
```

Comment: `var keys = _.keys(arrOfObjs);` isn't remotely what the OP's code does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I meant clean way

Comment: Well, as I said above, your code isn't remotely doing what the OP's code is doing. The equivalent would be `var firstKey = _.keys(arrOfObjs[i])[0];` vs. `var firstKey = Object.keys(arrOfObjs[i])[0];`. Adding a library doesn't make that cleaner.

Comment: you can consult the official documentation of [here](http://underscorejs.org/#keys)

Comment: Which only confirms what I've said above: It does exactly what `Object.keys` does. (Which I knew. I wouldn't presume to comment if I didn't.) I think you need to re-read the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, I'm sorry, you're absolutely right